# cast subclass to another subclass

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

how can a subclass be casted to another subclass with the same superclass? I know that it don't allow to cast directly from subclass to subclass. Another ways? ID is set into superclass, so it is not nice with making new object; I am using it for state pattern. If the state changes, then the typ of class should change.

```
@Entity
public class Request() {}

@Entity
public class OpenRequest extends Request() {}

@Entity 
public class CloseRequest extends Request() {}
```

Thanks

Comment: You are aware that that may fail at runtime, even if you get a workaround?

Comment: The state pattern is also different than you describe: a Request should HAVE a state, not BE a state.

Comment: Glenn, i am using before the enum for state of request, but I had to use a lot of 'if{}else{}' in some methods. It will clear at the code, if it should like presistent domain object: http://www.scribd.com/doc/55889067/45/Persistent-Domain-Object-Business-Object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't possible. If you could do this, you could always cast any reference to any other class, since all classes are subclasses of `Object`.
You will have to create a new instance of the class you want, and transfer the information manually.

Answer (score 1):

You don't cast classes, you cast references to *instances* of classes. And note that if you have an instance of one subclass and cast it to another subclass, that will cause a runtime error. You can only cast something to be something that it is (e.g., you can cast an `OpenRequest` as a `Request`, because all `OpenRequest`s are `Request`s); if you try to cast it to be something that it isn't (casting an `OpenRequest` as a `CloseRequest`, for instance), that will fail.

Comment: `you cast instances of classes` -> To be precise: - `you cast references to the instances of classes`